# I made an React app with React + Vite and deployed in Cpanel but it shows blank screen. How do I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm new to React and I build react apps using React + Vite app.
My projects run perfectly in development mode. I build an app using `npm run build` command. I get a 'dist' folder which is absolutely fine.

The problem is that when I deploy the dist folder in Cpanel I get a blank page on the webpage. No content is there inside `<body> </body>` of html when I inspect the page.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?
help me :'(

Comment: Can you include more information? What does the `index.html` file from the `dist` folder look like? How are you hosting the JS and CSS files? This is generally an issue with paths for import so you want to look at the `<link>` and `<script>` elements in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah I changed the path (removed "/") in the index.html and it worked. thanks!